# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "OR

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using python 2.7 and postgresql 9.3 with psycopg2 2.7.3, when I try to execute a select query while parameter passing it gives me this error
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "OR

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM test WHERE voucher= ? OR voucher= ?', ('RHAT', 'MSO'))
```

the error message is

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "OR"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Psycopg2 uses `%s` placeholders, not `?` questionmarks:

```
cur.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM test WHERE voucher = %s OR voucher = %s',
    ('RHAT', 'MSO'))
```

See the [*Passing parameters to SQL queries* section](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) of the Psycopg2 documentation.

Python database adapters generally stick with one or the other style (with accompanying named parameter styles). Always check the documentation to see what style is used. There is a [`paramstyle` variable](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) on the library, but that doesn't always reflect support for multiple styles very well.

Comment: When I trying to pass table name into a query it dosn't seem to work cur.execute('DROP TABLE %s ;', ('test',))

Comment: @Sameesh: a table name is not data, no. A placeholder escapes *data* specifically to not be mistaken for SQL instructions or object names.

Comment: See [Pass column name as parameter to PostgreSQL using psycopg2](//stackoverflow.com/a/27290006) for a method to include a tablename.